# In Weaviate, how to get the total count of vector search results when using pagination?

Tags: weaviate

We are using `nearText` filter in our vector search with pagination using `limit` and `offset` - as can be seen below is the code snippet using Weaviate Java SDK Client:

```
    NearTextArgument nearTextArgument = weaviateClient.graphQL().arguments().nearTextArgBuilder()
            .concepts(new String[]{ "basketball" })
            .certainty(0.6f)
            .build();
    Result<GraphQLResponse> result2 = weaviateClient.graphQL().get()
            .withNearText(nearTextArgument)
            .withClassName(...)
            .withFields(...)
            .withLimit(...)
            .withOffset(...)
            .run();
```

However, we need to provide a feedback to our API if there is still a valid `next page` (**e.g.** page 3 for a size of 25 data) for the search results, as well as the `total count of search hits` which I could not find in the documentation.

I read that one can use the `aggregate` function however, it does not support `withOffset`

Is there a way to perform vector search with pagination using offset and include the total count of hits? And if yes, I would appreciate a sample code snippet on how to achieve these requirements.